# Setting id columns with Django tables

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, html-table, django-templates

I have a table:

```
class Table(tables.Table):
    actions = tables.TemplateColumn(...)

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5', 'field6']
        attrs = {"id": 'id', 'class': 'class'}
```

I know that I an always change the row names:

```
    col_attrs = {
        'data-id': "adsas"
    }
```

which would make:

```
<table>
    <tr id="adsas">
      <td>..
      <td>..
    </tr>

    <tr id="adsas">
      <td>..
      <td>..
    </tr>
</table>
```

But unfortunately, I didn't find a similar thing for rows, I want to have this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td id="0">..
      <td id="1">..
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id="0">..
      <td id="1">..
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can someone show me how can I make a similar structure, or at least what attr to use for it ?